# Regex replace _ with \_ inside dollar signs

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
var str = "__Definition:__ $x_0$ is an _ordinary point_ of the ODE $L[y] = 0$";
```

I want to replace all underscores inside the `$$` so that the string becomse

```
var str = "__Definition:__ $x\_0$ is an _ordinary point_ of the ODE $L[y] = 0$";
```

How can I do this in javascript?

Comment: Not realy understanding what you want, your output is inconsistant as " is an _ordinary point_ of the ODE " is between two $ signs as well but in your example nothing happens to the _

Comment: I'm not certain if this is the best solution, thus the comment, but I suppose you could use backreferences to achieve this. You can try `str.replace(/([^$]*\$[^$]*)_([^$]*\$[^$]*)/g,'\$1\\_\$2')`. http://jsfiddle.net/qqrdU/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in a single regex replace call:

```
var str = "__Definition:__ $x_0$ is an _ordinary point_ of the ODE $L[y] = 0$";
var repl = str.replace(/_(?!(?:(?:[^$]*\$){2})*[^$]*$)/g, '\\_');
console.log(repl);
```

**Explanation**: It means match underscore character NOT followed by EVEN number of `$` signs. Hence `_` between 2 `$` signs will be matched and outside will not be matched (since those are followed by even number of `$` signs).

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/lAKto5

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good idea to use regex for such parsing activity but, if you want quick and dirty

```
var replaced = str.replace(/\$([^$]+)\$/, function(m, g) { 
  return '$' + g.replace(/_/, '\\_') + '$'; 
});
```